# Separating array in other arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array that I need to split in different arrays. I have an array of Strings and need to split it in different pages (different arrays).

At first, I get the length of the array, using

```
int size = array.length;
```

And then, I get the number of pages I need, knowing that each page should only have 10 Strings

```
int numberOfPages = (int) Math.floor(size/10);
```

The user then select which page he wants to see

```
int pageSelected = 2;
```

After that, I tried to split the array, but got some exceptions. I tried:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(array,(0+10*(pageSelected-1),10*10+(pageSelected-1)));
```

I get an exception when I try to print the values of the new array.

Is there anyway to split an array in 'pages', and display these 'pages' as requestes?

@Edit1
I get a Nullpointer Exception

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: What Exception do you get. Where do you get it?

Comment: Could you paste stacktrace?

Comment: The exception is a Nullpointer
The stacktrace is useless, as it was generated by Bukkit, and has no information regarding the code

Comment: @Kerooker: If it is a `NullPointerException`, that means your `array` is probably `null`. Although there are errors in your code. That's not the most important part right now...

Comment: @Kerooker and size at lest must be 10 ?!!!

Comment: int numberOfPages = (int) Math.floor(size/10);

Shouldn't this be Math.ceil(size/10)? If the size is 11 don't you want two arrays: ten elements in the first and one in the second?

Comment: @j_v_wow_d: it should be `Math.ceil((double) size/10)` because an integer division already floors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error probably occurs in this line:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(array,(0+10*(pageSelected-1),10*10+(pageSelected-1)));
```

Where there is an error with the brackets (the method requires three arguments, but from the method's perspective, you only provide two: the last two are grouped by brackets). You can use:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(array,10*(pageSelected-1),10*10+(pageSelected-1));
```

(removed `0+` since this has no use).

Furthermore you made a semantical error: `10*10+(pageSelected-1)` should be replaced by: `10+10*(pageSelected-1`

So the full line reads:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(array,10*(pageSelected-1),10+10*(pageSelected-1));
```

Although a better guideline would be to use small steps:

```
int i = pageSelected-1;
int g = 10*i;
Arrays.copyOfRange(array,g,g+10);//do something with the result
```

And to do it perfect, you better use variables for constants such that - if you change your mind - you can easily modify the number of items per page:

```
int i = pageSelected-1;
int perpage = 10;
int g = perpage*i;
Arrays.copyOfRange(array,g,g+perpage);//do something with the result
```

Finally a small remark: as @j_v_wow_d says, you should `ceil` the division, otherwise you will generate one page for `11` items. The correct code for `numberOfPages` is thus:

```
int numberOfPages = (int) Math.ceil((double) size/perpage);
```

Comment: for my learning goal, can you explain what 10*(pageSelected-1) means how did the op come up with it?

Comment: `10` is the number of items per page. The OP uses an offset of `1` of `pageSelected`. Thus you decrement it to get a *Java* array-index. To get the real page (`pageSelected-1`). Then you multiply it by `10` because every page has `10` items. To get the offset item.

Comment: and each page is in each index of an array or from zero to nine counts as a page?

Comment: I guess the OP processes the subarray by printing a webpage or something showing these items. Now of course one can also do the math by using indices with the calculated offset. By copying it however, things can be done a bit simpler.

Comment: great explanation I think you should add this to your post to be more perfect thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the `pageSelected` is indexed so that 0 is the first:

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
int pageSize = 2;
int pageSelected = 2;
final String[] pageData =
        Arrays.copyOfRange(
                array,
                (pageSelected * pageSize),
                (pageSelected * pageSize) + pageSize);
```

The outcome of this is that `pageData` contains ["e", "f"].

Answer (score 1):

You could just do `size / 10`; no need to `floor` or cast it.

Also, the `from` expression `10*10+(pageSelected-1)` should be `10 + (10 * (pageSelected - 1))`.

Comment: And a small brackets error... But that's indeed not the important part.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(array,(0+10*(pageSelected-1),10*10+(pageSelected-1)));
```

I think you mean this :)

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(array,0+10*(pageSelected-1),10+10*(pageSelected-1));
```

Look at the position of the `+` and `*` after the second comma.

But, it would be easier to read if it was not a one-liner

```
int offset = 10 * (pageSelected - 1);
Arrays.copyOfRange(array, offset, offset + 10);
```

Or even better

```
public static final int PER_PAGE = 10; 

/* (...) */

int offset = PER_PAGE * (pageSelected - 1);
Arrays.copyOfRange(array, offset, offset + PER_PAGE);
```